# Django aggregrate/annotate with additional join

Tags: django, django-models

I have two model classes: `Class A` which represents `table_a` and `Class B` which represents `table_b`. Is there a way to aggregate or annotate `Class A` to include the value of a field in `Class B` other than the column that is aggregated on?

The SQL query that would accomplish what I need is as follows:

```
SELECT
  a.*,
  b2.col2
FROM table_a AS a
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT
               max(col1) AS m,
               a_id
             FROM table_b
             GROUP BY a_id) AS b1 ON b1.a_id = a.id
  LEFT JOIN table_b AS b2 ON b1.a_id = b2.a_id AND b2.col1 = b1.m
```

But the aggregate function only returns the data that would be retrieved with this:

```
SELECT
  a.*,
  b1.m
FROM table_a AS a
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT
               max(col1) AS m,
               a_id
             FROM table_b
             GROUP BY a_id) AS b1 ON b1.a_id = a.id
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @sltn PostgreSQL